# Databricks: Sharing information between workflow tasks using Scala

Tags: scala, databricks, azure-databricks

In Databricks, I would like to have a workflow with more than one task. I would like to pass information between those tasks. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/workflows/jobs/share-task-context , this can be achieved with Python using

```
dbutils.jobs.taskValues.set(key = 'name', value = 'Some User')
```

and to fetch in second task

```
dbutils.jobs.taskValues.get(taskKey = "prev_task_name", key = "name", default = "Jane Doe")
```

I am, however, using jar libraries written in Scala 2.12 for my tasks.

Is there any way to achieve this in Scala? Or any ideas for workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/workflows/jobs/share-task-context), Scala is not supported with the [taskValues subutility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils#dbutils-jobs-taskvalues).

However, if you still want to get values around a task, you can create a global temporary view and access them.

In the example below, I tried with a Scala notebook, and the same Scala code can be added to your JAR while building it.

Output:

[image]

Code in **scalatask1**

```scala
case class taskValues(key: String, value: String)

val df = Seq(new taskValues("task1key1", "task1key1value"), new taskValues("task1key2", "task1key2value"), new taskValues("task1key3", "task1key3value")).toDF

df.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("task1Values")
```

Code in **scalatask2**:

```
spark.sql("select * from global_temp.task1values;").filter($"key"==="task1key2").select("value").collect()(0)(0)
```

Here, you get the task1 table and filter out the required key.

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution. However, I think it would not work if multiple instances of this workflow are running at the same time. As the global temp view would be shared across all workflows, they would interfere with each other / overwrite each other's values. Ok... maybe this could somehow be overcome by attaching the workflow ID to each entry...

Comment: Yes. Base on your usage you need to make it unique in someway. I suggest you to give unique keys across your workflows so no other task should modify it.

Comment: Ok this works: In the global temp view (which can also be a table, of course) I added a column called job_run_id, and I have configured my workflow tasks to accept "{{job.run_id}}" as first parameter for my library call. This is shared across all tasks of a workflow. Task one is writing my arguments together with this job_run_id to the table, and task 2 retrieves this record, using the job_run_id as filter condition.